# How to force html/css padding/margin on an element?

Tags: html, css

How can I add/force bottom margin/padding to the following <a> element ?

```
<p>
    <h31>Testing?</h31>
    <a style="margin-bottom: 200px">Create a new Entry</a>        
    testing padding
/*more stuff here...*/
```

Styles are very convoluted and the margin-bottom: 200px is not forcing the padding after the <a> element.

Comment: jsfiddle would be nice here, but add display:block to your <a> element. if that doesn't work add !important after your 200px declaration. but you shouldn't need that. also, make your h3 element and h3 and not a h31

Comment: Remember **margin!=padding**, try to understand what are your requirements and play with it to get the difference.

Comment: Thanks display: block; margin-bottom: 10px worked great!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `margin` CSS property doesn't work as expected when the elements are *inline*. Add `display:block`, or `display:inline-block` (in your case) to enable margins on inline elements (such as anchors).

The `padding` property is usually applied without trouble.